# SVN - merging/killing a branch

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

Within our repository we have a trunk that contains our app, a branch for "phase 2" features added on top of the app and then a branch of this branch with some single-sign-on functionality added into the app.

```
trunk/application
branches/application_phase_2
branches/application_phase_2_with_sso
```

No work has taken place in the trunk and any updates to **application_phase_2** have been merged-up to **application_phase_2_with_sso**.

The **application_phase_2** branch work is now complete and live, but **application_phase_2_with_sso** branch work is not finished yet.

I've succesfully merged **application_phase_2** back into the trunk, but wanted to kill (delete) this branch to stop others in the team from checking in any further work into it.

Will SVN allow me do this given the **application_phase_2_with_sso** branch?

If I can is there any impact on the **application_phase_2_with_sso** branch if I kill the branch it was taken from - once work is completed here can I merge this back to trunk directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will SVN allow me do this given the application_phase_2_with_sso branch?

Yes

> is there any impact on the application_phase_2_with_sso branch if I kill the branch it was taken from

No. In any case you delete only in "current" state, history doens't affected, stored in repo and can can used, when needed (and, and last, due to ",...any updates to application_phase_2 have been merged-up to application_phase_2_with_sso" `application_phase_2_with_sso` content is equal to "will be deleted" branch and will want nothing from parent)

Comment: And the command to do it is `svn delete`: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html